# App crash in IOS 7 working IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Custom cell(friendListCell) in my app. when i run this into an IOS 8 and later it works but in IOS 7 it crash and show error like below. i could not find the error where it present,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UILabel 0x17892a10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.'
```

Below the code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     return cell;
}
```

Note:
    I delete all the reference to this cell even though it shows error.

Comment: Show us some code, and point out where the crash happens. Note that you may need to enable exception breakpoints to see what triggers the exception.

Comment: you may be trying to set text without referencing Label's text property... You must be doing somewhere` lblTitle = @"data"` instead of `lblTitle.text = @"data"` ..

Comment: see my updated code and the breakpoint show the error when it comes to below line ,  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: in which Line it crashes..cell creation or in return cell ?

Comment: Have you tried other way of creating cell

Comment: ya u right! crash at cell creation

Comment: Ok let me try my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that you are setting a variable on a UILabel from inside the storyboard/xib file that doesn't exist.

You can change the code anyway you want and that won't fix the problem. The error is in your storyboard or xib file. Are you trying to set a variable called `keyPath` in your storyboard/xib file?

Comment: Got it! You correct. i mistakenly add keypath to uilabel which present in the actual viewcontroller . That should cause of error. but it work in IOS 8 . Thats y it confusing me lot. Ridicules!

Comment: You have discovered an undocumented property in iOS 8!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for creating Cell:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Comment: I used this before but now i want to add the identifier to storyboard as "list" and call it like above line of code..

Comment: so in place of `cell` use your identifier `list`

Comment: why we need to check cell == nil ?